# How to create content(bulleted list) in JQuery? The content I create using string does not look like list. How should I modify the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my page when I click on the Course Title, Course Description has to be displayed in a div(with id="prgdesc_rest"). When the course description is just one sentence(without any li tags) the result is fine(see image 1).

But when course description contains ul li-this just displays these tags as it is(see image 2).

I want to do some string manipulation and create the ul and li elements on the fly. What code should be written in my_jquery_functions2.js so that it should look like bulleted list(see image 3)?

--coursesPage.jsp--

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
              <script src="css/jquery.min.js"></script>
              <script src="css/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
              <script type='text/javascript' src='css/jquery.marquee.min.js'></script>            
              <script src="css/my_jquery_functions2.js"></script>
              <script>
                    var courseObj = JSON.parse('{ "courses":[{"courseId":"1001","courseTitle":"Core Java","courseDescription":"Core Java, OOPs, Multithreading, IO"},{"courseId":"1002","courseTitle":"Java Web Development","courseDescription":"<ul><li>Servlet</li><li>JSP</li></ul>"}]}');                  
              </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div data-pauseOnHover="true">
        <i><a href="#"><label style="color:blue" id='1001'>Core Java&nbsp;</label></a></i><br><br><br><br>
        <i><a href="#"><label style="color:blue" id='1002'>Java Web Development&nbsp;</label></a></i><br><br><br><br>                                       
    </div>
    You clicked
    <div id="pdesc"><span style="color:blue" id="prgdesc_before"></span>-<br><br><br><br>
    Course Description
    <div id="prgdesc_rest">
        <ul><li>Chapter 1</li><li>Chapter 2</li></ul>
    </div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

--my_jquery_functions2.js--

```
$(window).load(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < courseObj.courses.length; i++) {
        var courseId = courseObj.courses[i].courseId;
        var courseDescription = courseObj.courses[i].courseDescription;
        $("#" + courseId).data('course_index', i);
        $("#" + courseId).click(function() {
            var course_index = $(this).data('course_index');
            $("#prgdesc_before").text(courseObj.courses[course_index].courseTitle);
            $("#prgdesc_rest").text(courseObj.courses[course_index].courseDescription);
        });
    }

 });
```

---

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.html()` rather than `.text()` when setting the content.
`.text()` escapes any HTML that is passed to it so it displays like your second image